Taylor expansion or Itô's formula
Consider a risky asset whose price at time $t$ is $S_t$, and an option whose price at time $t$ is $P(t,S_t)$.
I do not understand how to justify the following Taylor expansion without using Itô's formula: denoting $\delta S_t=S_{t+\delta t}-S_t$,
$$
P(t+\delta t,S_t+\delta S_t)=P(t,S_t)+\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}(t,S_t)dt+\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(t,S_t)\delta S_t+\frac12\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}(t,S_t)(\delta S_t)^2.
$$
For example, when computing the PnL of a delta-hedge option between $t$ and $t+\delta t$, using Black-Scholes formula we get the following:
$$
PnL=\frac12S_t^2\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2}(t,S_t)\left(\frac{(\delta S_t)^2}{S_t^2}-\sigma^2\delta t\right),
$$
where $\sigma$ is the implied volatility. This justifies statements such as "we make money if realised vol > implied vol".
Clearly if we had used Itô's formula above, then $(\delta S_t)^2$ should be understand as the quadratic variation $\delta\langle S\rangle_t$ which is $\sigma^2S_t^2\delta t$. Then the PnL above would be always 0, which is obviously wrong.
So it means the first formula above is indeed a Taylor expansion and not Itô's formula, but then:

How do we justify the absence of $\delta t\delta S_t$, and of higher order terms? What justifies we consider $(\delta S_t)^2$? Why not $(\delta S_t)^3$ as well? I understand it in the context of Itô's formula with infinitesimal variation, which is not the case here.
If the answer is just something like "we apply Itô, but just not with an infinitesimal increment". Then what is the justification that $\delta\langle S\rangle_t$ is replaced by $(\delta S_t)^2$? Why not write $\sigma^2S_t^2\delta t$ instead?


In $\frac{\delta S_t^2}{S_t^2}-\sigma^2\delta t$, $\frac{\delta S_t^2}{S_t^2}$ is equal to $\hat\sigma^2 dt$ where $\hat\sigma$ is the realised volatility. If $\hat\sigma=\sigma$ then net PnL is zero but this is rarely the case.

Here $\delta S_t$ is definitely meant as an increase in the spot $S_t$, and not as the differential $dS_t$. So the expansion is a just a Taylor expansion. The higher terms are ignored because they probably don't matter at the moment.

In this answer I derive the PnL formula (that is similar to yours) rigorously using Ito calculus and no other hocus pocus.

Do not get confused by Taylor expansion vs differential and by small vs infinitesimal quantities.
The differential of a function $f(x,t)$ is
$$
f(x+dx,t+dt) - f(x,t) = df(x,t) = f_t(x,t) dt + f_x(x,t) dx
$$
If $x$ is stochastic the differential is (by Ito)
$$
df(x,t) = f_t(x,t) dt + f_x(x,t) dx + \tfrac12 f_{xx}(x,t) (dx)^2
$$
See also the comment by @TedBlack for the other part(s) of your question.

I've re-written my answer as there is a more direct way to see it, and you don't need stochastic calculus.
Take a real (smooth) function $f(t)$, you might want to know
$\Delta_f = f(T) - f(0)$
There are 2 ways to do it

Taylor expansion: $\Delta_f = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}T^i$ (start from 1 since we want the increment). $N$ can be chosen for a more or less stable / accurate approximation.

Integrating its derivative $\Delta_f = \int_0^T df(t) = \int_0^T f'(t) \, dt$


Which to chose depends on the particular situation. But, one can immediately see some differences

In the 2nd case, only the 1st derivative is used (unless you move to double - triple integrals)
Which one is better? Not sure is a valid question. The first case only uses information at $t=0$, the second only the 1st derivative, but everywhere.

Now, if $P$ is a payoff function which depends on $S_t$, so $P(t, S_t)$. As a function of $t$ and $s$, $P(t, s)$ is super smooth, but as a function of $t$, $P(t, S_t)$ is not.

no difference, but you need a 2D Taylor expansion (up to any order you like) and the increments are $\delta t$ and $\delta S_t$
$\int_0^T dP(t, S_t)$ is not a Lebesgue integral ($P(t, S_t)$ is not of finite variation), so you need Ito, no alternative.

And a final remark, the Taylor expansion is often used in PnL explain, the integral in the PnL of the continuous delta hedge.
